# How to create an empty std::tuple?

Tags: c++, stdtuple

I need to construct an `std::tuple` object so that `std::tuple_size<T>::value` = 0.
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I don't see the problem here...

Comment: what did you try and how did it fail?

Comment: i tried std::tuple() and had no clue what to try else. I didn't know that empty template brackets are a thing. How is this even implemented?

Comment: @DariusDuesentrieb, Just like the forward declaration in [a reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple). By the way, `std::tuple()` works as of C++17.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
std::tuple<> empty;
using empty_t = std::tuple<>;
auto empty2 = std::make_tuple();
static_assert(std::tuple_size<std::tuple<>>::value == 0);
```